# How to separate random numbers in intervals and then get the probabilities of said intervals in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability, normal-distribution

I have to generate 2000 float random numbers with a normal distribution using numpy in Python, then get the integer intervals of those numbers and finally calculate the frequency and probability.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what do you mean by "integer intervals"? Give some concrete inputs and sample outputs.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, We know the probability between (-1,1) in a normal distribution is 68% and If we test we see this is correct:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 0, 1 # mean and standard deviation
rnorm = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 2000)

freq = np.sum(np.logical_and(rnorm>=-1, rnorm<=1))
print(f'frequency between (-1,1): {(freq)}')

prob = freq/2000*100
print(f'probability between (-1,1): {prob} %')

# Or (-2,2) is 95% and (-3,3) is 99.7 like below:
# >>> np.sum(np.logical_and(rnorm>=-2, rnorm<=2))/2000*100
# 95.85000000000001
# >>> np.sum(np.logical_and(rnorm>=-3, rnorm<=3))/2000*100
# 99.7
```

Output:

```
frequency between (-1,1): 1365
probability between (-1,1): 68.25 %
```

You can use `plt.hist` *(you can change bin as you want)* and then compute frequency and probability like below:

```
plt.hist(rnorm, bins=50)
plt.show()

freq = rnorm[rnorm < 0]
print(f'frequency less than ZERO: {len(freq)}')

prob = rnorm[rnorm < 0]
print(f'probability less than ZERO: {len(freq)/2000*100} %')
```

Output:

[image]

```
frequency less than ZERO: 1003
probability less than ZERO: 50.14999999999999 %
```